# MediaWiki + latex => json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence

Tags: mediawiki

I've just finished installing MediaWiki on a fresh CentOS 7 droplet on Digital Ocean. Everything seems to work fine, except that when I type in a math formula, I get the following error message:

```
A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software.
```

In my Apache error_log, I see the following:

```
[Sun Dec 07 13:35:13.131206 2014] [:error] [pid 20894] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53015] PHP Warning:  json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in /var/www/mediawiki/includes/json/FormatJson.php on line 237, referer: https://wiki.*******.net/index.php?title=Test&action=edit
```

If I remove math formulas from the page, the page gets saved in the database without issues. I've followed the instructions given here:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math

I need server-side rendering to be able to use some custom packages as well as a bunch of include files that we typically add to the preamble. This would be hard/impossible to accomplish using MathJax.

Precise steps done:

1. Installed httpd, mariadb mod_ssl through yum.
2. Downloaded newest mediawiki and untar'd to /var/www/mediawiki
3. Created user and database into mariadb for mediawiki
4. Ran the standard mediawiki installation script installing with this username into the created db.
5. Copied generated LocalSettings.php into /var/www/mediawiki (at this point the site worked without issues)
6. Installed the texlive with extras package through yum.
7. Installed OCaml through yum.
8. Downloaded the Math extension and compiled the texvc and texvccheck binaries (they are in their default locations)
9. Added the following lines to LocalSettings.php: require_once "$IP/extensions/Math/Math.php";
10. At this point writing any math into a page will cause the error described above when pressing "save page".

The offending code is the following:

```
// PHP escapes '/' to prevent breaking out of inline script blocks using '</script>',
// which is hardly useful when '<' and '>' are escaped (and inadequate), and such
// escaping negatively impacts the human readability of URLs and similar strings.
$options = JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES;
$options |= $pretty !== false ? JSON_PRETTY_PRINT : 0;
$options |= ( $escaping & self::UTF8_OK ) ? JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE : 0;
$options |= ( $escaping & self::XMLMETA_OK ) ? 0 : ( JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP );
$json = json_encode( $value, $options );
if ( $json === false ) {
    return false;
}
```

Obviously the math code will include a slash in the closing tab. However, I don't see this warning printed in the error_log for any non-math related tag.

Comment: Which instructions did you follow? **Exactly what did you do?** It's not sufficient to simply link to a page containing a tutorial; you need to explain what changes you actually made.

Comment: Except it's not my code, so I assume this is an installation issue and not a bug that I would need to fix. I can of course file something in their Bugzilla.

Comment: I know the maths system for media wiki has had quite a major overhall recently and it may not be completely tested on all systems. A drastic solution might be to go with a previous version about 6 months ago. If MaxSem's answer does not work you could try changing the maths preference.

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` is unrelated. You just need to follow the [Math installation instructions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math#Installation) and run `php maintenance/update.php` from shell to create a database table for this extension.